# Python: Elementwise difference for multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the [**minimum image separation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions#.28A.29_Restrict_particle_coordinates_to_the_simulation_box) between two sets of particles. I have about 40 particles in each set, and their position vectors (three dimensional) are stored in two arrays of dimension `(40, 3)`. I have to compute the Euclidean distance between **each** of the particles in one set, and **each** of the particles in the other, after applying the minimum image criterion. To make it clearer, a one-dimensional equivalent of the same would be, for two lists `pos1` and `pos2` with the coordinates, `[func(i-j) for i in pos1 for j in pos2]` where `func = lambda x: x - np.rint(x/width)*width` is a function which applies the minimum criterion.

In three dimensions, the Euclidean distance would be `numpy.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dx**2)` where `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` are returned by `func` for each dimension.

*(The function `func` is just to demonstrate how minimum image criterion is applied. I do not use the same exact program structure.)*

I am looking for an efficient way to do this, as I have to do the same operations as part of analysing multiple data sets, each with about **20000** time steps, and each time step containing 3 sets of 40 particles each, i.e. **6** combinations of sets to compute for each timestep, in each data set.

Googling led me to [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) but I am having trouble optimising the computations time. The inbuilt routines for distances (Euclidean, Minkowski, Manhattan, Chebyshev etc.) are optimised and run pretty fast *(upto three orders of magnitude in my tests below)*, in comparison to explicit function definitions given as arguments:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, euclidean

In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: pos1 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: pos2 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: cdist(pos1, pos2, metric='euclidean')
   ...:
The slowest run took 12.46 times longer than the fastest. 
This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.3 µs per loop

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: pos1 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: pos2 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: cdist(pos1, pos2, metric=euclidean)
   ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 43 ms per loop

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: pos1 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: pos2 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: cdist(pos1, pos2, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum()) )
   ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 15.5 ms per loop

In [6]: width = 1.0

In [7]: func = lambda x: x - np.rint(x/width)*width

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: pos1 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: pos2 = np.random.rand(40, 3)
   ...: cdist(pos1, pos2, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((func(u)-func(v))**2).sum()) )
   ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 31.2 ms per loop
```

Here is what I have considered as options:

- Explicitly loop over array elements and build the required array *(probably the least efficient)*
- Separate array into the three `x, y, x` components, apply minimum image criterion, and use `cdist` for calculating euclidean distances for each component individually (because `numpy.sqrt(dx**2) == dx` and so on), reconstruct `(40, 3)` array from the component arrays, and repeat `cdist` for calculating distances in 3D

What would be an efficient way to calculate the equivalent of `cdist(pos1, pos2, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((func(u)-func(v))**2).sum()) )`?

---

### Question:

Is there any inbuilt NumPy function that can give an equivalent of `[(i-j) for i in pos1 for j in pos2]`, but for specified axis of two arrays?

An example representation for what I intend to achieve:

```
    [ a  0  0 ]           [ x  0  0 ]
A = [ b  0  0 ]  ;    B = [ y  0  0 ]
    [ c  0  0 ]           [ z  0  0 ]

              [ a-x  0  0 ]
              [ a-y  0  0 ]
              [ a-z  0  0 ]
              [ b-x  0  0 ]
     Result = [ b-y  0  0 ]
              [ b-z  0  0 ]
              [ c-x  0  0 ]
              [ c-y  0  0 ]
              [ c-z  0  0 ]
```

*(All values are `float`, and the operation is to be done for all columns.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I've understood exactly what you want to do... should I have, you can do an elementwise difference using broadcasting, see below

```
In [24]: a = np.random.random((5,3))
In [25]: b = np.random.random((5,3))
In [26]: c = a[:,None,:]-b
In [27]: c[3,4]
Out[27]: array([ 0.55732535,  0.30270483,  0.48249629])
In [28]: a[3]-b[4]
Out[28]: array([ 0.55732535,  0.30270483,  0.48249629])
In [29]: c[0,3]
Out[29]: array([ 0.28562698,  0.33227255,  0.35890964])
In [30]: a[0]-b[3]
Out[30]: array([ 0.28562698,  0.33227255,  0.35890964])
In [31]:
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Didn't know it was this straightforward... Now I can apply the minimum image criterion directly on the array.

However, after reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), I hope I understand `a[:,None,:]-b` correctly: The elementwise comparison is now `a[0,None] - b[0]`, `a[1,None] - b[1]` and so on. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: It seems that `a[:,None]-b` also gives the same result as `a[:,None,:]-b` for two 2D arrays that I tried. How exactly does `a[:,None,:]` work?

Comment: @KrishnadevN: You can always add `:` to the right of an index, and it will have no effect. So for a 2d array, `mat[0]` is the same as `mat[0,:]`

Comment: @Eric : Okay, but the array is 2D. So is `a[:,None,:]` converting my 2D array to 3D and doing the operations?

Comment: `None` doesn't "use up" a dimension when indexing, so the second `:` is still referring to the second axis of the input

Comment: @Eric Oh okay. Thanks!